# Mysql COUNT where user is NOT event participant

Tags: mysql, sql, join, count, relation

I want to count all entries in a participation through table for events where either there is no entry for a user or where the explicit user has no entry for the event.

Example: I have 13 events and 2 users.

User A (which is the user I use for the query) has participated in two events (event 1 and event 2). 
User B has also participated in two events (event 2 and event 3). 
No one has participated in any of the other events.

If I query with `WHERE event.userId = "User A"` I get the correct count 2

If I query `WHERE event.userId IS NULL` do I get the correct count 10

But if I query `WHERE event.userId IS NULL OR event.userId != "User A"` I get the count 13 (but it should be 11)

```
SELECT 
    COUNT(DISTINCT event.id) AS count
FROM 
    event 
LEFT JOIN 
    event_participation participation ON participation.eventId=event.id

###    
# WITH USER    
###

# With this where clause I will get the correct count with the user
#WHERE participation.userId = "de9d0de5-5b2f-4108-8df7-6b89ec539679"            

###    
# WITHOUT USER
###

# Tried participation.userId != "de9d0de5-5b2f-4108-8df7-6b89ec539679" for ??? after OR, but this is not correct
#WHERE participation.userId IS NULL OR ???
```

The solution should be a single count result for all entries like that:

[image]

How can I achieve this?

Comment: What is wrong with your current query?  It should already be working.

Comment: Please add sample data to your question.

Comment: Okay I added it to the question

Comment: No...I mean add sample table data for the tables in question, and then show us the expected output.  Do not leave any details open to possible misinterpretation.

Comment: What is the meaning of `WHERE event.userId IS NULL OR event.userId != "User A"`? Why should the result be 11?

Comment: It should be 11 in my example, because I only want to count the entries where the user did NOT participate and he participated in two events and in total there are 13.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Count the non matching rows of the join to get the number of events where `'UserA'` is **NOT** a participant:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT e.id) AS count
FROM event e LEFT JOIN  event_participation p 
ON p.eventId = e.id AND p.userId = 'UserA'
WHERE p.eventId IS NULL
```

or since `id` is the primary key of the table `event`:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS count
FROM event e LEFT JOIN  event_participation p 
ON p.eventId = e.id AND p.userId = 'UserA'
WHERE p.eventId IS NULL
```

or with `NOT EXISTS`:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS count
FROM event e 
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT 1 FROM event_participation p 
  WHERE p.eventId = e.id AND p.userId = 'UserA'
)
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=085464ac5586a1cbbf224302698fd3a7).
Results:

```
> | count |
> | ----: |
> |    11 |
```

Comment: Thanks! The second solution works for me pretty well

Comment: Can you explain why it is working. I am not sure why you added the user which should be excluded from the result to the join and why it is working in this way.

Comment: This condition:`ON p.eventId = e.id AND p.userId = 'UserA'` joins the tables where the rows match for the current event and the specific user. Then the condition: `WHERE p.eventId IS NULL` filters out all these matching rows. The result is all the unmatched rows and this is what you want.